# Where can I find music notes for classical guitar and lute online?

Tags: sheet-music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sites with a good selection of sheet music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/696/sites-with-a-good-selection-of-sheet-music)

Occasionally, I search for music notes online, e.g. for pieces by Sor, Dowland, Bach and others. Are there some good resources for musical notes (or tabs)? I am interested in classical guitar and lute compositions.

I have seen this question ([What is the legality of online tabulature?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/what-is-the-legality-of-online-tabulature)) and agree with the shadowy (and often ad-cluttered) ambiance of some of these sites. Are there some legal, maybe even well-organized, too?

Comment: If you're seriously into classical guitar music, then you would have to *buy* actual books! Even then, many of these books are hard to find!

Answer (score 6):

You need to specifically be searching for '"sheet music" piece name', not musical notes.

Some pieces by Sor and Bach can be found here http://classicalguitar.homeip.net/Sheetmusic.htm

This was the first link from the Google search ["sheet music classical guitar"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sheet+music#hl=en&sugexp=evnsp&xhr=t&q=sheet+music+classical+guitar&cp=22&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0&aqi=&aql=t&oq=sheet+music+classical+&pbx=1&fp=ab718b42c52c1c5f)

Answer (score 3):

Please pay for them and stick with the masters:

Andres Segovia:
[http://www.amazon.com/Andres-Segovia-Studies-Guitar-Transcribed/dp/0793504368](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0793504368)

Paco DeLucia:
[http://www.amazon.com/Scores-Fuente-Caudal-Visual-Spanish/dp/0786675063](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786675063)

Julian Bream: http://www.sheetmusicplus.com/s?q=Julian+Bream

Comment: Paco De Lucia, isn't a classical guitar player.

Answer (score 3):

What is probably the largest online collection of lute music in the world is at http://gerbode.net/ (and mirrors). There are currently more than 3,000 pieces available (actually, I think it may be closer to 4,000 by now), many in several different arrangements. All of them are available in [Fronimo](http://www.theaterofmusic.com/fronimo/) file format, and most of them are also available in TAB, PDF, and MIDI.

You mentioned Dowland. A quick glance shows [more than 100 pieces](http://gerbode.net/ft2/composers/Dowland/) by him alone. There are 588 Fronimo files under his directory, including separated parts for SATB singers.

The collection is entirely free -- both in price and in copyright. *All* of the pieces are transcriptions by Sarge Gerbode, either from the originals or scans of the originals made available to him by libraries. This collection represents many years of work by him and it has been a labor of love. I'm currently working with Sarge to put a much nicer front end on the collection and we hope to have the up and running by Summer, if not sooner.

Check out the site. You can contact him at sarge@gerbode.net, or me at peter@techbuddy.us.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at International Music Score Library Project http://imslp.org/

Answer (score 1):

I answered this for a different question, but it might be useful here:

You can find a lot of music sheets on http://www.ultimate-guitar.com/ Most of them are modern songs, or older music on modern instruments, but I also found a lot of classical guitar and lute pieces there. Some of the files can only be viewed with proprietary software (like Guitar Pro) but there are free ones as well.

If you are interested in even older music which is even harder to find, you can find some medieval music (mostly for lute or for flute) here> http://www.terrasoft.hu/kultura/consort/kotta/