# Free Sheet Music? Please?

Tags: sheet-music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sites with a good selection of sheet music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/696/sites-with-a-good-selection-of-sheet-music)

I am musician and I keep needing new music score. I was wondering where I could get sheet music for free? Can you recommend any legit sources?
Thank you!

Comment: If it is good music it is worth paying money for. Music is written by your fellow musicians and they need to earn money from writing it. If you expect to earn money from playing music, you need to be willing to support your fellow musicians by paying money to them for their compositions.

Comment: This question is not constructive because "sheet music" is too broad. Bluegrass banjo? Gregorian chant? Broadway show tunes? Edo period shakuhachi?

Comment: @WheatWilliams no that's not a fair response. I could say the same of software, but lots of people produce free software. There is also lots of sheet music that's old enough for the copyright to have expired.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't talking about public domain sheet music! I use IMSLP.org, CPDL.org and the like to get Baroque and Classical sheet music all the time. I think Susan Petbow is asking where to get sheet music of recent compositions that are under copyright, without paying for it. She didn't indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

[IMSLP](http://imslp.org/) has an extensive collection of sheet music.

Answer (score 2):

I am musician too and I face the same "problem" every single time. I can recommend you one of the nice resources I've discovered for myself - a big collection of [free sheet music](http://www.musicaneo.com/sheetmusic/free/) for various instruments and genres.
They have a very handy score filter there, so you adjust type of scoring, difficulty level, etc.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

www.8notes.com is a good one, though it doesn't have everything.